# ConvertTo-Json ignores array in the inner object

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, object, powershell-5.1

I have an object I need to extend. The issue is after converting to JSON the inner array object is always empty. I don't understand where's my fail :(

```
$settings = @{}

# create the nested object
$settings | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name nested_obj -Value @{}

# extend the nested object with an array property
$settings.nested_obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name nested_property -Value @( "1", "2" )

# {"nested_property":["1","2"]}
Write-Host ( $settings.nested_obj | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100 )

# {"nested_obj":{}} - the nested object is unexpectedly empty
Write-Host ( $settings | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100 )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConvertTo-Json` sees the object stored in `$settings` is a *hashtable*, and so rather than serializing properties, it starts serializing dictionary entries - of which you have none.

Either attach the `nested_obj` and `nested_property` values as dictionary entries:

```bash
# create root hashtable/dictionary
$settings = @{}

# create the nested hashtable
$settings['nested_obj'] = @{}

# add an entry to the nested hashtable
$settings['nested_obj']['nested_property'] = @( "1", "2" )

# {"nested_obj":{"nested_property":["1","2"]}}
Write-Host ( $settings | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100 )
```

... or, use actual (non-dictionary) objects

```bash
# create object hierarchy
$settings = [PSCustomObject]@{
  nested_obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
    nested_property = @( "1", "2" )
  }
}

# {"nested_obj":{"nested_property":["1","2"]}}
Write-Host ( $settings | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100 )
```

The PowerShell 2.0-equivalent, using `Add-Member`, would be fairly similar to your initial attempt, with the difference that we replace `@{}` with `New-Object psobject`:

```
$settings = New-Object psobject
$settings | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name nested_obj -Value (New-Object psobject)
$settings.nested_obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name nested_property -Value @( "1", "2" )

# {"nested_obj":{"nested_property":["1","2"]}}
Write-Host ( $settings | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100 )
```